# How do I load QBytesArray containing a zip file to QuaZip?

Tags: c++, qt, quazip

I'm using Qt Creator in a new project, so I don't know many things about this... :(
I want to download a zip file, containing a json file, read this file and use that information. I can download the zip, save it in my disk and open it again to read json and use it. But I want to open my zip just in memory without really saving it...
I have the zip info in a QByteArray and I need to send this "file" to QuaZip constructor/object.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QBuffer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuffer.html). It provides a QIODevice interface for a QByteArray.

**Example:**

```
QByteArray byteArray("abc");
QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
buffer.seek(3);
buffer.write("def", 3);
buffer.close();
```

Then you can use [QuaZip::QuaZip(QIODevice *ioDevice)](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/classQuaZip.html#ae52ebadd5ce64cdb49d7e198904b0b8c) constructor to create QuaZip object.

Comment: thank you
it works now
QString MainWindow::extractAll_fomVar(QIODevice *ioDevice) {
    ioDevice->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QuaZip archive(ioDevice);
    archive.setZipName("list.zip");
    ioDevice->close();
    archive.open(QuaZip::mdUnzip);
......

Comment: Unfortunately, it was working because I still had my zip file inside project folder... I still have the errors:
QuaZip::open(): set either ZIP file name or IO device first 
QIODevice::read: device not open

Comment: Firstly, if you use QTcpSocket to download archive you don't need use QByteArray and QBuffer at all. Qt sockets implement QIODevice interface.
Secondly, probably problem may be in your code not in conception.

Comment: I'm using this: QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.post(networkRequest, params); this way I can receive my zip file. I can save it in my disk, read it, extract files and use them... But I don't want to save that zip... I only want to use it in memory.
So... If I can download it, save it, read it again and use it, Why can't I use it without saving it to my disk?

Comment: I might have found the answer here: http://qtshanoir.gforge.inria.fr/html/classQuaZipFile.html#ad31592e0e8a9eaa009c6c0e2040a2158

but will test it